# SublimeText3 build on the server over SSH

Tags: linux, ssh, makefile, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

Let's say I'm on local macOS and need to edit/run something on remote Linux server using SSH.

I would like to hit `Build` on ST3 so that it executes Makefile on the server. Am I being to imaginative or that's possible? Which tools might help to make the dream a reality?

It seems something similar was asked before https://superuser.com/questions/1214210/sublime-text-terminal-control?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: This clearly is a development question, but I don't understand it. If you are editing a file using ssh, why are you using ST3? Isn't ST3 a GUI application? Why don't you use an editor running on the server like vi, emacs or nano, like most people do?

Comment: In fact I still need to improve some skills to reach Nirvana, I use to use vi  (in the way u mean) for quick fix only - I fill more confortable on ST. Perhaps I should consider @RobinGreen approach more seriously. But really, most people (which do edit/run over ssh) go by vi approach? What about the IDE addicted ones, are they out of the game?

Comment: But my point is, for quick file edits, editing on the server is fine. For serious code changes, shouldn't you be committing and then deploying, so that you have a record in version control and can easily roll back if something goes wrong? In which case you could use a workflow where you deploy from a CI/CD server instead.