# SublimeText set settings on the fly

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I was looking on how to make ST build on the server ([SublimeText3 build on the server over SSH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50403222/sublimetext3-build-on-the-server-over-ssh)) and found and answer at RemoteCpp (https://packagecontrol.io/packages/RemoteCpp).

RemoteCpp `"remote_cpp_cwd": "~"` setting  allows change the current working directory in the remote server (it would be nice to have some way to navigate across dirs), as described at:

https://github.com/ruibm/RemoteCpp/blob/master/Default.sublime-settings

However (to my eyes) its impractical to edit `Preferences.sublime-settings` every time I want to navigate to another directory to i.e. execute `make`.

Is there any ST shortcut so that set the `remote_cpp_cwd` can be done kind of on the fly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sublime Text 3: Reset font size to custom font size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46790515/sublime-text-3-reset-font-size-to-custom-font-size)